# How to hide deeply a file/folder in windows

Tags: windows

I want to hide a folder on windows so it cant be shown even if the option show hidden files is enabled , like the playready cache folder 
(C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\PlayReady\Cache).
Any idea ?
Thanks

Comment: not possible.  If the user has the permissions to view the contents of a folder they can see all contents in that folder.  If they don't have the permissions to view the contents of the folder, then in that specific example, that Cache folder couldn't be used for anything.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Burgi - I only want facts.  I consider speculation, to be worthless, and a waste of my time.  Stick to productive helpful constructive comments.

Comment: As you can see there is no folder called Cache
![Playready Folder](http://i65.tinypic.com/n1cm7p.png).

but when I add "Cache" to the path , I can then see Its contents
![permissions](http://i68.tinypic.com/10o3dq8.png)

I have the read/write permission , and ![the option show hidden files is enabled](http://i66.tinypic.com/vgpm3m.png) , 
and despite all that the folder is hidden


Im writing a c# ,and I want to hide some backup files like that , is there any way to do that ?

Comment: You don't even understand that the answer you accepted blatantly didn't answer your question. See my comment to the "answer".

Comment: people tend to encrypt rather than hide.. there is truecrypt so you could have a file with whatever name. And open that and it reveals a whole folder structure. There is another option for more hidden files   sysinternals has a tool to show them. It's like attaching a file onto a file. It's a very dirty tactic.. it's a thing called streams.

Comment: I just want to hide a folder , so it cant be shown  if this option is enabled http://i66.tinypic.com/vgpm3m.png . I know its easy to found it , but  thats help me in my case

Comment: if you want to show files you tick both options.  If you want to hide files you tick both options

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can hide folders/files as "protected operating system files". This will make sure that the users cannot see the file even if they select "Show hidden files, folders, and drives". However, if they uncheck the **Hide protected operating system files** option they will still be able to see them.

[image]

Open a Command Prompt and type:

> attrib +s +h "C:\Users\MyUser\Path_Here"

To unhide it is:

> attrib -s -h "C:\Users\MyUser\Path_Here"

Source: [Make a Super Hidden Folder in Windows Without any Extra Software](http://www.howtogeek.com/104825/make-a-super-hidden-folder-in-windows-without-any-extra-software/)

Comment: -1 He wrote "I want to hide a folder on windows so it cant be shown even if the option show hidden files is enabled"

Comment: @barlop This is simulates the file being a protected operating system file, which is a bit more than what was asked for. Sure, it's still easy to get around but I think most people overlook this option.

Comment: The +s simulates? you mean it simulates but doesn't make it so? you give no source for this  I think you are suggesting a layer of complexity that doesn't exist.

Comment: I suppose the questioner overlooked the system option but it's just as simple as the hidden option, and both options are necessary to show the files.